# Outputting Map<String, Map<String,List<String>>> in jsp using jstl

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, html-table

I've data in the below format.

```
Map<String, Map<String,List<String>>>
```

example - `{ProfileAdaptarRepository={active=[true,false,true,true]}}}`

I did set page context in `mymap` in the below scriptlets and it works absolutely fine.

```
<%  pageContext.setAttribute("mymap",example);%>
```

I need data in the below html tabular format:

[image]

Sample HTML source code for the above image.

```html
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>Component</th>
   <th>Properties</th>
   <th>J01</th>
   <th>J02</th>
   <th>W01</th>
   <th>W02</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>StoreConfiguration</td>
   <td>active</td>
   <td>true</td>
   <td>false</td>
   <td>true</td>
   <td>false</td>

  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td>DynamoConfiguration</td>
   <td>enabled</td>
   <td>true</td>
   <td>false</td>
   <td>true</td>
   <td>false</td>

  </tr>
 </table>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

I tried to present the above data in webpage using the below `jstl` code, but it didn't work for plural component values (more than 1 components)

```
<c:forEach var = "comp" items="${mymap}">
    <tr>
        <td>${comp.key}</td>
        <c:forEach var="prop" items="${comp.value}">
             <td>${prop.key}</td>
             <c:forEach var="val" items="${prop.value}">
                  <td>${val}</td>
             </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Can someone please help or guide me in achieving the desired tabular format?

Many Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: It is generally considered bad practice to use really nested Collections (Map<String, Map<String,List<String>>>). This won't be readable to anyone else that works on the code in the future. Heck, in six months when you come back to this code, you might not remember what it does. I'd strongly recommend changing your data structure to actual classes (even if it is as general as Row and Column). This will help you iterate through your forEach lists too.

Comment: @Allen, Many Thanks for your views. I agree with you it's bad code. It's actually not a Web page which doesn't change,  so I ended up with this mess and this should be suffice to deal with Java source code. I can't go back and change back java source code as I had spent lot of time in formatting this map. So,  it would be of great help if you pass me the solution.  I'm relatively new to java Web programming ...:) thank you..

Comment: @harshavmb You will spent much more time trying output it or trying to make changes in the future, for an example for sorting. So, It will be better, if you use a list of plain DTO objects. One object per table row.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code with multiple components. I created a data structure like yours with

```
        List<String> myListStore = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> myListDynamo = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> myListProfile = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, List<String>> myMapStore = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, List<String>> myMapDynamo = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, List<String>> myMapProfile = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> myBigMap = new HashMap<>();

        myListDynamo.add("true");
        myListDynamo.add("false");
        myListDynamo.add("true");
        myListDynamo.add("false");
        myMapDynamo.put("enabled", myListDynamo);
        myBigMap.put("Dynamo", myMapDynamo);

        myListStore.add("true");
        myListStore.add("false");
        myListStore.add("true");
        myListStore.add("true");
        myMapStore.put("disabled", myListStore);
        myBigMap.put("Store", myMapStore);

        myListProfile.add("true");
        myListProfile.add("false");
        myListProfile.add("true");
        myListProfile.add("true");
        myMapProfile.put("disabled", myListProfile);
        myBigMap.put("Profile", myMapProfile);

        request.setAttribute("mymap", myBigMap);
```

I used your exact jstl code and was able to generate the table. Are you sure that your data is in the correct format in the data structure?